# MediaElement & DispatcherTimer in strictly timing application

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, dispatcher

I'm currently developing a WPF application which requires strictly timing, says, being late 2 seconds matters.

I have a MediaElement mediaPlayer which seeks to a new position and play every time a Dispatcher timer is fired. But I notice that the mediaPlayer.Position is not very synced with the timer. In the example below, I set the dispatcherTimer fired after 55 seconds, but the value received from MessageBox in timer_Tick is 108.276746, which is late 2 seconds (55 + 55 = 110).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(55);
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            mediaPlayer.Source = new Uri("test.wma", UriKind.Relative);
            _currentPosition = 55;
            mediaPlayer.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_currentPosition);

            timer.Start();
        }
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Position" + mediaPlayer.Position.TotalSeconds);// print around 108 seconds
        }
```

This is the problem because I need the mediaPlayer position is perfectly synced with the dispatcher timer.

For more information, the root problem here is: **the dispatcher timer to strictly follow the mediaElement progress**, because I need to sync other controls with the position that mediaPlayer. Being late 2 seconds is unacceptable. Does anyone know how to achieve this effect?

**UPDATE PURPOSE**: I'm trying to "switch illustration image" according to the playing position from an audio. For example, when the narrator read to "... We have a beautiful house" in the audio, the program will show pictures of a beautiful building. But now since the position is late, it will show the picture long before the audio mentions it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out, it takes time for the media elements to load, therefore it is not wise to use a countdown timer. You should do the the other way round: the DispatchTimer fires say like 1 or 2 times every second, and when it's fired you check the position of the media element. If it's at a certain position then show the picture.

This approach also limits the maximum error do the time interval of your DispatchTimer events, assuming that the system fires them accurately.

Comment: my workstation is broken and can't play media after re-installation, so I think it will take a little more time. Just to let you know that I don't forget this question.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the media element a lot.

My suspicion is that the timer is fine ( give or take a few ms ) 
but the mediaplayer position is definitely guaranteed not to be where you expect it to be.

The 2 seconds could well be accounted for in loading the video file and loading the video/audio codecs.  further more, if there is any lag at all ( cpu or ram spike or other ) the mediaplayer will also lag while the timer will not.

perhaps setup a scenario where the video is guaranteed to be loaded ( for example pausing it somewhere in the middle of the video ) then start the timer and play the video from there to check.

Comment: how can I guarantee that the video has loaded? The pause technique seems not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a video player that doesn't have the MediaElement's slow initialization time for videos, try Jeremiah Morrill's [MediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/) project. He has made some great improvements including load times.  It is also open source so if you need more or information on where you're at in the video, you can add that to the source.